# PowerMockito for testing MapReduce Code

Tags: java, mapreduce, powermock

I have the following reducer Code and i am trying to use PowerMock to test it .
package com.cerner.cdh.examples.reducer;

```
public class LinkReversalReducer extends TableReducer<Text, Text, ImmutableBytesWritable> {

    @Override
    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        StringBuilder inlinks = new StringBuilder();

        for (Text value : values) {
            inlinks.append(value.toString());
            inlinks.append(" ");
        }

        byte[] docIdBytes = Bytes.toBytes(key.toString());

        Put put = new Put(docIdBytes);

        put.add(WikiConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY_BYTES, WikiConstants.INLINKS_COLUMN_QUALIFIER_BYTES,
                Bytes.toBytes(inlinks.toString().trim()));

        context.write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(docIdBytes), put);
    }
}
```

Below is the test i have written for the above:

```
@Test
public void testLinkReversalReducer() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Text key = new Text("key");
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Context context = PowerMockito.mock(Context.class);
        Iterable<Text> values = generateText();

        StringBuilder inlinks = new StringBuilder();

        for (Text value : values) {
            inlinks.append(value);
            inlinks.append(" ");
        }

        LinkReversalReducer reducer = new LinkReversalReducer();

        byte[] docIdBytes = Bytes.toBytes(key.toString());

        byte[] argument1 = WikiConstants.COLUMN_FAMILY_BYTES;
        byte[] argument2 = WikiConstants.INLINKS_COLUMN_QUALIFIER_BYTES;

        byte[] argument3 = Bytes.toBytes(inlinks.toString().trim());

        Put put = new Put(docIdBytes);
        put.add(argument1, argument2, argument3);

        reducer.reduce(key, values, context);

        Mockito.verify(context).write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(docIdBytes), put);
    }

    private List<Text> generateText() {
        Text value = new Text("AB");
        List<Text> texts = new ArrayList<Text>();
        texts.add(value);
        return texts;
    }
}
```

So the thing is that my Mockito.verify(context).write(new ImmutableBytesWritable(docIdBytes), put); seems to get called with the right values in place and also my junit result shows that the Invoked and the Actual give the same response. But the test still seems to fail. Does anyone have a clue ? . Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you provide the failure message or stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, that the `Put` class does not define an `equals` method. Therefore the `verify` method thinks that the actual `Put` passed to `context.write` inside your`LinkReversalReducer.reduce` method is different to the expected `Put`assembled in your `testLinkReversalReducer` method.

To work around this problem you could do the following:

```
Mockito.verify(context).write(Mockito.eq(new ImmutableBytesWritable(docIdBytes)), MockitoHelper.eq(put));

...

class MockitoHelper {
    public static Put eq(final Put expectedPut) {
        return Mockito.argThat(new CustomTypeSafeMatcher<Put>(expectedPut.toString()) {
            @Override
            protected boolean matchesSafely(Put actualPut) {
                return Bytes.equals(toBytes(expectedPut), toBytes(actualPut));
            }
        });
    }

    private static byte[] toBytes(Put put) {
        ByteArrayDataOutput out = new ByteArrayDataOutput();
        try {
            put.write(out);
            return out.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```